# Errors when attempting to run object detection

Tags: python

The code that im trying to run

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
cap.set(3,640)
cap.set(4,480)

classNames = []
classFile = 'coco.names'
with open(classFile, 'rt') as f:
    classNames = f.read().rstrip('\n').split('\n')

configPath = 'ssd_mobilenet_v3_large_coco_2020_01_14.pbtxt'
weightsPath = 'frozen_inference_graph.pb'

net = cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(weightsPath, configPath)
net.setInputSize(320, 320)
net.setInputScale(1.0/ 127.5)
net.setInputMean((127.5, 127.5, 127.5))
net.setInputSwapRB(True)

while True:
    success,img = cap.read()
    classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img, confThreshold= 0.5)
    print(classIds, bbox)

    for classId, confidence, box in zip(classIds.flatten(),confs.flatten(),bbox):
        cv2.rectangle(img,box,color=(0,255,0),thickness= 3)
        cv2.putText(img,classNames[classId-1].upper(),(box[0]+10, box[1]+30),
                    cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX,1,(100,255,50),2)

    cv2.imshow("Output", img)
    cv2.waitKey(1)
```

after running the code, there are errors that occurred such as;

```
C:\Users\david\PycharmProjects\ObjectDetectionTest2\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/david/PycharmProjects/ObjectDetectionTest2/main.py
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wvn_it83\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (434) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\david\PycharmProjects\ObjectDetectionTest2\main.py", line 23, in <module>
    classIds, confs, bbox = net.detect(img, confThreshold= 0.5)
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.5.1) C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-wvn_it83\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\resize.cpp:4051: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !ssize.empty() in function 'cv::resize'
```

Many people said that this occurred because the image directory isn't the same or the image contains zero pixels. I have tried to move the coco, pbtxt, pb files to the same directory as the main.py file but it still did nothing.

However, since this is my first time coding and I followed a tutorial on youtube, I have very little knowledge about coding and I hope you can help in human language lol.
Any help and insights would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you try to put the full path to all the files.

Comment: The key to debugging is to print intermediate values to make sure they match what you expect.  Try `print(img.shape)` to see if the image has a size.

Comment: @TimRoberts thank you for the response! I added 'print(img.shape)' at the last line of my code and it still gave me the same errors as before. any insights?

Comment: @PrabhatKumarSahu thank you for your insight! Where should i put the full path? and how exactly should i do this? I have read a lot of people giving this solution.

Comment: Do you check the `success` flag? Seems important under the circumstances...

Comment: Update: When i debugged, it says img = none on the specific line. I saw the guy on youtube and he did not face any of this problems.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thank you for the help but im afraid that i do not understand what you mean lol. excuse my stupidity....lol

Comment: I think the problem is that the python could not access my video camera thus no images are being processed?

Comment: UPDATE: IT WORKED, THANK YOU, EVERYONE!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

If you are not using a webcam, it should be `VideoCapture(0)`.